# Position of Cells where the mid point of graph lies

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data.

```
x       y
0.00    0.00
0.03    1.74
0.05    2.60
0.08    3.04
0.11    3.47
0.13    3.90
0.16    4.33
0.19    4.59
0.21    4.76
0.20    3.90
0.18    3.12
0.18    2.60
0.16    2.17
0.15    1.73
0.13    1.47
0.12    1.21
0.14    2.60
0.17    3.47
0.21    3.90
0.23    4.33
0.26    4.76
0.28    5.19
0.31    5.45
0.33    5.62
0.37    5.79
0.38    5.97
0.42    6.14
0.44    6.22
0.47    6.31
0.49    6.39
0.51    6.48
```

I used `=max()/2` to obtain the 50%th percentile, which in this case is `3.24`.

The point `3.24` does not exist for the `y` values but it falls in between the `3.04` and `3.47`.

How can I find the address of these 2 cells?

Note: The 50th percentile also hits on the other part of the graph, but I only require the first instance.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you data in columns A and B, with header row in 1 (first numbers in row 2).  Assuming you =max()/2 formula is in D2

Use aggregate to determine the first row where the Y value exceeds you mean.  Then do it again and subtract 1 from the row.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$32)/(B2:B32>D2),1)
```

That will return the row number of 6.   First occurrence exceeding the value in D2.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$32)/(B2:B32>D2),1)-1
```

That will give you row number of 5.

use the row numbers in conjunction with INDEX and you can pull the X value.

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$32)/(B2:B32>D2),1)-1)
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$32)/(B2:B32>D2),1))
```

That will give you the X values.  if you want the corresponding Y values, simply change the index look up range from A:A to B:B.

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$32)/(B2:B32>D2),1)-1)
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$32)/(B2:B32>D2),1))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!